# How can I reduce the number of angry passengers at a stop?

Tags: cities-in-motion

It seems on so many of my routes I'll get 1-2 stops that have 100+ angry passengers waiting at them. At some point adding more vehicles doesn't do any good, as they get too congested and end up causing long queues.

What are some other tactics for reducing the queue size?

Answer (score 2):

You need a complete solution like building the metro ... to remove the people waiting you can delete the bus stop (and then they'll walk over to the new location)

You can also increase the ticket price a little, and lower salary a little to free up some cash.

Consider making some direct routes from point A to B if you can figure out where a batch of the people are trying to get to.

Answer (score 0):

You might benefit by reading the below:

http://citiesinmotion.wikispaces.com/FAQ

http://citiesinmotion.wikispaces.com/Hints

Comment: Welcome to Gaming, Douglas! We try to avoid answers that are only links, in case the links go down, etc. It is also just nicer for the asker to have the information here, as well. :)